# For which real $a$ does the series $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(1+6k)^{ia}}-\frac{1}{(5+6k)^{ia}}$ vanish?

Tags: sequences-and-series

The question is to find when will $L(\chi, s)$ of $\chi=\left(\frac{-12}{n}\right)$ vanish. So  $\left(\frac{-12}{n}\right)$ is defined as the Jacobi symbol for odd $n$ ($\chi($even$)$=0). Using quadratic reciprocity I got $$\left(\frac{-12}{n}\right)=\left(\frac{-1}{n}\right)\left(\frac{3}{n}\right)\left(\frac{4}{n}\right)=\left(\frac{n}{3}\right)$$ so we have $$L(\chi,s)=\sum_{n=1\pmod 3, n\,\text{odd}}\frac{1}{n^s}-\sum_{n=2\pmod 3, n\,\text{odd}}\frac{1}{n^s}.$$ And we are only interested in when $s=ia$. How can I find where $L(\chi, s)$ vanish for those $s$?

Comment: Sorry for the naive question, but how it is supposed to be defined for real part equal zero? If I take as definition the classical exponential, then we have a sum of complex numbers on the circle of radius 1 , and it's not clear at all to me that this converges. Are we meaning implicitly an analytic extension as in the Zeta case?

Comment: anything unclear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your character is $\chi(n)=(\frac{n}3)1_{2\ \nmid\ n}$, the Dirichlet series is $L(\chi,s)=\sum_{n\ge 1}\chi(n)n^{-s}$.

It doesn't converge anywhere on $\Re(s)=0$. You need the analytic continuation, for a non-trivial Dirichlet character it amounts to $L(\chi,it)=\lim_{\sigma\to 0^+}L(\chi,\sigma+it)$.

$$L(\chi,0)=\lim_{s\to 0} L(\chi,s)=\lim_{s\to 0} s\int_1^\infty (\sum_{n\le x} \chi(n))x^{-s-1}dx$$

The mean value of $\sum_{n\le x} \chi(n)$ is $\frac23$.

$\sum_{n\le x} \chi(n)-\frac23$ is periodic zero-mean implies that
$$\int_1^\infty (\sum_{n\le x} \chi(n)-\frac23)x^{-s-1}dx$$ converges for $\Re(s) > -1$. Whence
$$L(\chi,0)=\lim_{s\to 0} s\int_1^\infty \frac23 x^{-s-1}dx= \frac23$$

Next, following the [same argument as for $\zeta(s)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Proof_sketch) we can show that $L((\frac{n}3),s)\zeta(s)$ has no zeros on $\Re(s)=1$, whence $L((\frac{n}3),s)$ has no zeros on $\Re(s)=1$. The functional equation implies that $L((\frac{n}3),s)$ has no zeros  on $\Re(s)=0$, and $$L(\chi,s)=(1+2^{-s})L((\frac{n}3),s)$$ implies that its zeros on $\Re(s)=0$ are at $\frac{(2 \Bbb{Z}+1)i\pi}{\log 2}$.

Comment: Thank you for your nice solution! But I am a bit lost when you refer to the prime number theorem. Do you mean we need to prove nonvanishing of $L((\frac{n}{3}),s)\zeta(s)$ on $\Re(s)=1$ similar to that of $\zeta(s)$?

Comment: Yes I mean the $\left|\zeta(x)^3\zeta(x+iy)^4\zeta(x+2iy)\right|=\ldots$ part of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Proof_sketch it relies on the non-negativity of the coefficients of $\log\zeta(s)$ and that $(s-1)\zeta(s)$  is analytic on $\Re(s)\ge 1$ and non-zero at $s=1$. The same holds when replacing $\zeta(s)$ by $L((\frac{n}{3}),s)\zeta(s)$

Comment: Thanks! I got it.